# AsyncTask Upload Video Freeze the UI

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

While Uploading video to server the UI freezes until video upload is completed, i did lot of googling and read stack overflow post but didn't get any solution. Any help would be highly appreciated. Video is uploaded successfully but the problem is that app UI is freezing.

Here a call to Asynctask which Upload Video to server.

```
AsyncVideoUploader client_ = new AsyncVideoUploader(false,ApiTask.CREATE_POST_VIDEO,this);
client_.execute("file1", videoPath, serviceArgs_);
```

And here is the actual Asynctask to upload video.

```
public class AsyncVideoUploader extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String> {
private AsyncTaskListener delegate;
private ApiTask task;
Object[] payload;
int responseCode = -1;
String responseMessage = "";
boolean isStartTimer = false,isSentMaxSize = false;
int maxSizeToSent;
int progressValue;
Timer timer = new Timer();

public AsyncVideoUploader(boolean secure, ApiTask task, AsyncTaskListener delegate) {
    this.task = task;
    this.delegate = delegate;
    payload = null;
}

public AsyncVideoUploader(boolean secure, ApiTask task, AsyncTaskListener delegate, Object... payload) {
    this.task = task;
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.payload = payload;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected String doInBackground(Object... args) {

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection_ = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream_ = null;
    // DataInputStream dataInputStream_ = null;

    int bytesRead_, bytesAvailable_, bufferSize_;
    byte[] buffer_;
    int maxBufferSize_ = 1*1024; // 8 Megabytes max

    String endLine_ = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens_ = "--";
    String boundary_ = "*****";

    String videoName_ = (String) args[0];
    String videoPath_ = (String) args[1];
    String fileName_ = Utils.getFileNameFromPath(videoPath_);
    long lengthOfFile;
    int total = 0;

    Map<String, String> serviceArgs_ = (Map<String, String>) args[2];

    FileInputStream inputStream_ = null;
    try {
        inputStream_ = new FileInputStream(new File(videoPath_));
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        URL url_ = new URL(Consts.URL.VIDEO_UPLOAD_HTTP); 
        httpURLConnection_ = (HttpURLConnection)url_.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection_.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection_.setDoInput (true);
        httpURLConnection_.setDoOutput (true);
        httpURLConnection_.setUseCaches (false);
        httpURLConnection_.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        httpURLConnection_.setConnectTimeout(Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
        httpURLConnection_.setReadTimeout(Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
        httpURLConnection_.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpURLConnection_.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        httpURLConnection_.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary_); 
        httpURLConnection_.connect();

        dataOutputStream_ = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection_.getOutputStream()); 

        // Video
        dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(twoHyphens_ + boundary_ + endLine_);
        dataOutputStream_.writeBytes("Content-Disposition:form-data;name=\"" + videoName_ + "\";filename=\"" + fileName_ + "\"" + endLine_); 
        dataOutputStream_.writeBytes("Content-type:application/octet-stream" + endLine_);
        dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(endLine_);
        bytesAvailable_ = inputStream_.available();
        lengthOfFile = new File(videoPath_).length();
        maxSizeToSent = bytesAvailable_;
        bufferSize_ = Math.min(bytesAvailable_, maxBufferSize_);
        buffer_ = new byte[bufferSize_];
        bytesRead_ = inputStream_.read(buffer_, 0, bufferSize_);
        while (bytesRead_ > 0)
        {

            total += bytesRead_;
            try {
                dataOutputStream_.write(buffer_, 0, bufferSize_);
                publishProgress((int)((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             bytesAvailable_ = inputStream_.available();
             Log.e("Bytes Available:", ""+bytesAvailable_);
             bufferSize_ = Math.min(bytesAvailable_, maxBufferSize_);
             bytesRead_ = inputStream_.read(buffer_, 0, bufferSize_);
        }
        dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(endLine_);


        // Other arguments
        Iterator<String> serviceArgsIterator_ = serviceArgs_.keySet().iterator();
        while(serviceArgsIterator_.hasNext()) {
            String key_   = (String) serviceArgsIterator_.next();
            String value_ = (String) serviceArgs_.get(key_);

            dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(twoHyphens_ + boundary_ + endLine_);
            dataOutputStream_.writeBytes("Content-Disposition:form-data;name=\"" + key_ + "\"" + endLine_);
            dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(endLine_);
            dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(value_);
            dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(endLine_); 
        }

        dataOutputStream_.writeBytes(twoHyphens_ + boundary_ + twoHyphens_ + endLine_);
        dataOutputStream_.flush();
        dataOutputStream_.close();
        inputStream_.close();

        if (httpURLConnection_.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return Utils.convertInputStreamToString(httpURLConnection_.getInputStream());
        }
        else {  
            this.responseCode = httpURLConnection_.getResponseCode();
            this.responseMessage = httpURLConnection_.getResponseMessage();

            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(httpURLConnection_ != null) {
            httpURLConnection_.disconnect();  
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    String response_ = Utils.getValid(response);
    if(Utils.isValid(response_)) {
        if(Utils.isValid(this.payload)) {
            this.delegate.onTaskComplete(this.task, response_, this.payload);
            return;
        }
        else {
            this.delegate.onTaskComplete(this.task, response_);
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        this.delegate.onTaskError(this.task, "Service is temporarily unavailable > " + this.responseMessage , this.responseCode);
        return;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(final Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    Log.e("Bytes uploaded", String.valueOf(values[0]));
    progressValue = values[0];
    delegate.onProgressUpdate(task , progressValue, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: why not show progress dialog?

Comment: the requirement is to don't show the progress dialog because the video upload process can be time consuming, so that's why we want the user to use App while video is uploading is background.

Comment: If so please use a service to upload the video to the server

Comment: @GeorgeThomas i also tried it with android IntentService. but no effect UI still freezes.

Comment: I got the solution of my problem, because i call publishProgress is while loop and it's call so frequently in the loop which causes the UI to freeze because publishProgress run on the UI thread. What i do is to call the publishProgress after certain interval of time. that solve my problem.